# Trying to get values of multiple inputs in an object and key will be index(0, 1, 2,3, 4,5) and values it's input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, frontend

I created five inputs and I am trying to get their values in an object after `click` on the button. The problem I am facing is that after the button click I am getting only `index` and `value` of last updated input.

```
function App() {
  const [dataItem, setDataItem] = useState({});
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  function getMultipleInputValue(index, e) {
    let newObj = {}
    newObj[index] = e.target.value;
    setDataItem(newObj)
  }

  function getDtat() {
    console.log("dataItem", dataItem)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {arr.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <input type='text' name={index} key={data} onChange={(e) => 
          getMultipleInputValue(index, e)} />
        )
      })}
      <button onClick={() => getDtat()}>Click here</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes I would expect that since you’re directly setting the state variable to a new object that contains only the last clicked key/value.  Read https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're resetting the state with a new object:

```js
  function getMultipleInputValue(index, e) {
    let newObj = {}
    newObj[index] = e.target.value;
    setDataItem(newObj) // resets the state to a new object
  }
```

Instead, what you need to do is update the current state object:

```js
  function getMultipleInputValue(index, e) {
    setDataItem(newObj => ({...newObj, [index]: e.target.value}))
  }
```

Please check the [fixed demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rogptd?file=src%2FApp.js).

See also [React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) on how to update the state based on the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use all the previous values of the current state, and update the new value, something like this:

```
setDataItem(prevState => Object.assign({}, prevState, newObj));
```